# Deleting rows from a table

Tags: jquery

I have a Table where a User can delete rows

While deleting , If there is only one row present, 
I need to remove the Erase Button dynamically

So that User cannot delete all the rows

I have tried as following

```
$(".butnBorrar").click(function(event){

   if($("#MyTable tr").length==2)
   {
    $(this).find('td:last-child').remove();
   }
   else
   {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/44avhkas/33/

Could you please let me know how to do this ? So that for the last row The Erase Button will be removed dynmaically

Comment: you need remove button errase, what row count was one?

Comment: Post your [mcve] here, not only on jsFiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one.

If the count is 2, it removes the cell after the 2nd to last row is removed.  It's not an IF/ELSE Condition.

```
$(".butnBorrar").click(function(event){


  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  if($("#MyTable tr").length==2) // accounts for table header
  {
    //window.alert("In Here");
        $("#MyTable tr").find('td:last-child').remove();
  }

});
```

Comment: Works Perfectly fine , thanks a lot , One More question incase if the row is added dynamically can we add the Erase button again ?

Comment: thats a diff question...but in that case...rather than removing the button...it would have been recommended to hide it instead so its still in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".butnBorrar").click(function(event) {
    //test the number or rows on tbody only
    if($("#MyTable tbody tr").length <= 1) {
        //use closest to get the parent tr
        //then hide the button
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td.total button').hide();
    }
    else {
        //else remove row
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```